Is undertaking lab research on the USA Visa Waiver program allowed?
I am a UK medical student and wanted to do some lab research this summer.
I got in contact with a university professor and sorted out a 11-week project at his lab. I also received a grant from a charity to cover the travel and living expenses of this project.
I am unsure if I require a visa for this. I am British passport holder. I looked at the US government website and saw that the UK was on the visa waiver exception. This means I can:

attend short-term training (you may not be paid by any source in the United States with the exception of expenses incidental to your stay)

enroll in a short recreational course of study, not for credit toward a degree (for example, a two-day cooking class while on vacation)


I am assuming that a 11-week project will qualify normally for the B1 visa, as this is not an official training program or internship, and is unpaid and not for academic credit. I found this information here: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html.
But I am wondering if this is sufficient? Or should I be trying to get the university to sponsor a J1/F1 visa?
I tried emailing the UK embassy, but they said it is ultimately the border officer who decides if I get in. But I don't want to risk anything at that stage.
Thanks for your help.

You may have a hard time convincing people that this is not for credit. An 11 week lab course in your chosen field of study is a long way from a 2 day cooking class. Also who benefits from this study? If any commercial entity benefits then this will be counted as work, paid or not.

Would be just me and the lab. No commercial entity. Right, will try for a J1 visa then.

I'd ask the charity sponsoring you. If this is what they spend their money on they'll have lots of experience with visas. They might even be able to make some of the arrangements for you.
